# Filter table from multiple widgets action in ArcGIS Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis, esri

I have two table widgets. When the user selects a value from Widget 1, it filters "Table A" on the map based on the selected Category. However, when the user selects a value from Widget 2, I want "Table A" to be filtered on the map based on the combined selection from both Widget 1 and Widget 2.

Here's the structure of "Table A":

```
ObjectID Category Zone

1   1   1
2   2   1
3   1   2
4   3   2
```

The filtering logic should work as follows:

When the user selects a value from Widget 1, "Table A" should be filtered to show only rows where the Category matches the selected value.

When the user selects a value from Widget 2, "Table A" should be filtered to show only rows where both the Category matches the selected value from Widget 1 and the Zone matches the selected value from Widget 2.

For example:

If the user selects Category 1 from Widget 1, the table should be filtered to show rows with ObjectID 1 and 3.

If the user then selects Zone 1 from Widget 2 (while Category 1 is still selected in Widget 1), the table should be further filtered to show only the row with ObjectID 1.

How can I implement the filtering based on both widgets' selections effectively?